# Using Cython To Link Python To A Shared Library

Tags: python, c, linker, cython, distutils

I am trying to integrate a third party library written in `C` with my `python` application using `Cython`. I have all of the python code written for a test. I am having trouble finding an example for setting this up.

I have a `pyd/pyx` file I created manually. The third party has given me a `header file (*.h)` and a `shared library (*.so)`. As far as I can tell, there are no other dependencies. Can someone provide an example of how to set this up using `Cython` and `disutils`?

Thanks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Sure !

(In the following, I assume that you already know how to deal with `cimport` and the interactions between `.pxd` and `.pyx`. If this is not completely the case, just ask and I will develop that part as well)

The sample (grabbed from a C++ project of mine, but a C project would work pretty much the same) :

**1. The Distutils setup file :**

Assuming that the extension to be created will be called `myext` and the 3rd party shared library is `libexternlib.so` (note the **lib*** prefix, here)...

```
# setup.py file
import sys
import os
import shutil

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

# clean previous build
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if (name.startswith("myext") and not(name.endswith(".pyx") or name.endswith(".pxd"))):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        if (name == "build"):
            shutil.rmtree(name)

# build "myext.so" python extension to be added to "PYTHONPATH" afterwards...
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [
        Extension("myext", 
                  sources=["myext.pyx",
                           "SomeAdditionalCppClass1.cpp",
                           "SomeAdditionalCppClass2.cpp"
                       ],
                  libraries=["externlib"],          # refers to "libexternlib.so"
                  language="c++",                   # remove this if C and not C++
                  extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp", "-O3"],
                  extra_link_args=["-DSOME_DEFINE_OPT", 
                                   "-L./some/extra/dependency/dir/"]
             )
        ]
)
```

**Note :** Your external `.so` file is linked via the `libraries` option :

```
libraries=["externlib"]   # Without the 'lib' prefix and the '.so' extension...
```

Note : the `sources` option can be used to get some additional source files compiled.

**Important :** `myext.pxd` (do not confound with `.pyd` - Windows stuff) and `myext.pyx` should be in the same directory. At compile time the definition file, if it exists, is processed first ([more](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html)).

**2. Then run it as follows :**

After having changed directory to the one containing your `myext.pxd`, your `myext.pyx`, as well as the above `setup.py` script :

```
# setup.sh
# Make the "myext" Python Module ("myext.so")
CC="gcc"   \
CXX="g++"   \
CFLAGS="-I./some/path/to/includes/ -I../../../DEPENDENCIES/python2.7/inc -I../../../DEPENDENCIES/gsl-1.15"   \
LDFLAGS="-L./some/path/to/externlib/"   \
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Where :

- `libexternlib.so` is assumed to be located at `./some/path/to/externlib/`
- `yourheader.h` is assumed to be located at `./some/path/to/includes/`

Note : **`CFLAGS`** could also have been setup using the `extra_compile_args` option :

```
extra_compile_args=["-I./some/path/to/includes/", "-fopenmp", "-O3"]
```

Note : **`LDFLAGS`** could also have been setup using the `extra_link_args` option :

```
extra_link_args=["-L./some/path/to/externlib/", "-DSOME_DEFINE_OPT", "-L./some/extra/dependency/dir/"]
```

Once distutils is done with the build, you get some new files, specially the `myext.cpp`, `myext.h` and most importantly, the `myext.so`.

**3. After that, you're good to go :**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./some/path/to/externlib/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:./some/path/to/myext/

# Run some script requiring "myext.so"
python somescript.py
```

Where your freshly created Python extension can be imported by its name :

```
# somescript.py
import myext
from myext import PySomeFeature
...
```

**Note** about Optimization : By default `-O2` is used for compiling the extension, but this can be overloaded (see above setup where `-O3` is specified).

**Note** about Cython paths : If Cython was installed in a custom directory, you might want to add it to your environment, before all :

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18 export PYTHONPATH;
PATH=$PATH:../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18/bin; export PATH;
```

Well, hope I covered the main points...

Comment: Hey, Thanks for all your help. I am getting the following error: ld: library not found for -lMYLIB where MYLIB.so is the file I am trying to link against - any ideas?

Comment: forget it, i just read that the gcc -l command assumes your *.so is prefaced with lib so i removed that and it found it and seems to be working.

Comment: Very good code - except what's with the trailing backslashes toward the end?  You don't need 'em (you're in parentheses) - in general, you NEVER need trailing backslashes in proper Python (always do it with parens, braces, or brackets).

Comment: How can I embed the libexternlib inside the python module (for shipping purpose)?

Comment: @Dilawar Not sure what you mean by "shipping". Once the library is released, the only requirement is to have its containing folder's path added to the environment (`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH`- See 3rd point of the above answer). Use absolute paths and add those export commands to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: Very very useful tips just in one answer

Comment: useful but `-DSOME_DEFINE_OPT` will be fined for the linker, but usually the compiler needs extra defines

Comment: @Gauthier Boaglio thanks for answer, it helped. Can you also help with packaging this as a wheel?