# how to include -std=c++0x while extending python with c++

Tags: python, c++

I am embedding Python with c++. 
i am using to_wstring() in my c++ function and the c++ code gets compiled when i add -std=c++0x. 
But while compiling python code using python setup.py build 
i get the following warning and error

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++     [enabled by default]
test.cpp: In function ‘std::wstring convert_to_wstring(unsigned char*, int)’:
test.cpp:180:57: error: ‘to_wstring’ was not declared in this scope
                     w_string += to_wstring(stream[i]) + L".";
```

how to add -std=c++0x in Python compilation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer in the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993927/using-cython-to-link-python-to-a-shared-library

Thanks