# Cython fails to compile, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find

Tags: python, c, linux, gcc, cython

Running into error stating:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnumsolver
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Upon running:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
ext_modules = cythonize(Extension("cy_rbisect",
            ["cy_rbisect.pyx"],
            library_dirs=['../clib'],
            libraries=['numsolver']))
)
```

My 'library files' are numsolver.h, numsolver.c, numsolver.o, numsolver.so

with Cython files: cy_rbisect.pxd, cy_rbisect.pyx.

I've already run the export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/path/to/numsolver.so' so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here... 
My code did work previously but then I renamed all the files updated the header/c/pyx/pxd files respectively and re-compiled. It hasn't been working since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I haven't used cython myself, but I found this: [Using Cython To Link Python To A Shared Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993927/using-cython-to-link-python-to-a-shared-library)

This might help you write your correct `setup.py` with your custom shared library. My old answer was targeted for a general solution as to how to compile and link shared libraries.

---

(*old answer*)

How are you compiling your library? For the linker to find your library in a non standard path, you have to use `-L` option. So the `gcc` command should look like this:

```
gcc <your *.o files> <your other options> -L /path/to/ -lnumsolver
```

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must have the directory path of where your library is found. And the filename has to begin with **lib**. So rename your so file to `/path/to/libnumsolver.so` and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/path/to/`. This variable should be used when you are trying to execute your code.

Take a look at [Shared libraries with GCC on Linux](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)